# Xpath: return only nodes with content

Tags: xml, xpath

When i use this xpath query:

```
>xpath //XmlFeed/ProductList/Product/ProductGroup
```

1000 results are returned, which is correct. However of the 1000 results, 700 are nil-elements, such as:

```
<ProductGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
```

and the rest does have data:

```
<ProductGroup>
<ID>100</ID>
<Description>Something cool</Description>
</ProductGroup>
```

Is it possible to change the query so that I only get results that are not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add predicate to get only `ProductGroup` having child element(s) :

```
//XmlFeed/ProductList/Product/ProductGroup[*]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
//XmlFeed/ProductList/Product/ProductGroup[*!='']
```

Answer (score 0):

This one gives you all results which do not have the `xsi:nil` attribute at all (btw. it does not check the `xsi:nil` value itself). But it may fit to your problem.

```
//XmlFeed/ProductList/Product/ProductGroup[not(@xsi:nil)]
```